# easiest way to get classpath jars for the Play framework?

Tags: java, playframework

I don’t see any easy artifact to download. For context, a Controller is a Java class, hosted by the controllers' package, and sub-classing play.mvc.Controller [1]

[1] https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way was for me to download them from Typesafe repository at https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/maven-releases/play/